# is it possible to use certificates on windows firewall?

Tags: windows, firewall, certificate

Scenario:

I have a situation where I work from home. I need to connect to a database server on the internet. The server has whitelist rules for IP addresses on firewall. My IP address changes constantly (isp uses dynamic ip). I have no control over whitelisting or ip address. I must contact to server admin to whitelist my ip everytime it changes.

---

So, Is it possible to use certificates to let know the database server's firewall my identity?